# VB.NET Email with multiple embedded Images

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image, email

Please can someone give me some pointers on how to send an email with MULTIPLE embedded images.

I can send a basic email and I can also send an email with an single embedded image using AlternateView,

In bodyText as XElement I have : `<img src='cid:SCREENSHOT'/>`

Then I add the alternative view like this:

```
Dim htmlContent As AlternateView =    AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyText.ToString(), Nothing, mediaType)

    If (IO.File.Exists(screenshotPath)) Then

        Dim screenshot As New LinkedResource(screenshotPath)

        screenshot.ContentId = "SCREENSHOT"
        htmlContent.LinkedResources.Add(screenshot)

    End If

    msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlContent)`
```

I just cant work out how to get multiple images in there.

Many Thanks

Richard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It involves 2 loops.

1 loop at the point of creatng the body.

Call this from BodyText using: `<%= CreateImages(imagePaths, hasCustImage) %>`

```
Private Shared Function CreateImages(ByVal imagePaths As IList(Of String), ByVal hasCustImage As Boolean) As XElement

    Dim images As XElement = <span></span>
    Dim temp As XElement = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 0 To imagePaths.Count - 1

        Dim img As String = String.Format("cid:ItemImage{0}", i + 1)

        If ((i = (imagePaths.Count - 1)) And (hasCustImage)) Then

            temp = _
                <p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt">
                    Customer:<br/>
                    <img src=<%= img %>/>
                </p>

        Else

            temp = _
                <p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt">
                    <img src=<%= img %>/>
                </p>

        End If

        images.Add(temp)

    Next

    Return images

End Function
```

Another loop to create the Alternative views:

```
msg.Body = bodyText.ToString()

    Dim htmlContent As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyText.ToString(), Nothing, mediaType)

    For i As Integer = 0 To imagePaths.Count - 1

        If (IO.File.Exists(imagePaths(i))) Then

            Dim itemImage As New LinkedResource(imagePaths(i))

            itemImage.ContentId = String.Format("ItemImage{0}", i + 1)
            htmlContent.LinkedResources.Add(itemImage)

        End If

    Next

    msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlContent)

    Return Utils.Send(msg)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add multiple linked resources. To clarify:

In your body, add multiple image references:

```
 <img src='cid:SCREENSHOT1'/>
 <img src='cid:SCREENSHOT2'/>
```

In your code, add multiple images:

```
If (IO.File.Exists(screenshotPath1)) Then
    Dim screenshot As New LinkedResource(screenshotPath1)
    screenshot.ContentId = "SCREENSHOT1"
    htmlContent.LinkedResources.Add(screenshot)
End If

If (IO.File.Exists(screenshotPath2)) Then
    Dim screenshot As New LinkedResource(screenshotPath2)
    screenshot.ContentId = "SCREENSHOT2"
    htmlContent.LinkedResources.Add(screenshot)
End If
```

(This seems a bit too simple. If I misunderstood your question, please say so.)

Comment: It is simple, BUT the number of images is not fixed and could range from one to say 10.

Comment: @Richard: Then make a loop. Do you need help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before in C#. Started with Bitmap objects and linked them into my HTML source with LinkedResource IDs. Then I attached the AlternateView containing the HTML source as the e-mail body to my MailMessage.

```
        String id1= "yourid";
        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<img src=cid:" + id1 + ">",null, "text/html"); // add to html as required

        Bitmap rc_img1 = new Bitmap(rc_bar.GetBitmap());

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        rc_img1.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        LinkedResource myImg1 = new LinkedResource(ms);
        myImg1.ContentId = id1;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(myImg1);

        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Comment: Hi. Is that not just adding a single image though?

Comment: Yes but you can add as many as you like this way aslong as they have different IDs.

Comment: @Brissles: Then I don't really see the point in your answer. As Richard writes in his question: `I can send a basic email and I can also send an email with an single embedded image using AlternateView`. He already knows how to do *that*.

Comment: You can send as many as you like using this method. As I said.