# What is the best method to store images in db for email sending?

Tags: database, vb.net, email

Hi Im a newbie in stackoverflow!
As mentioned on the question title, I've been storing the email's image path into the db via localhost. Once the email is sent and received, my outlook automatically block the image download and I will need to manually download it (Not a big issue here).
Then I started to wonder what if my website/server is down? If it is down, the email will not be able to locate and download the image at all. So I'm wondering if there is any alternative ways to display the image without worrying bout the availability of my server.
Thanks in advance for any incoming advises/replies!

Comment: So, are you sending an HTML email or an email with an image attached? I.E. are you including the actual image or just a link?

Comment: @SpectralGhost Hey, I'm inculding the actual image in the email. I.E <img src='imgurlpath'/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your primary concern seems to be about failure mitigation and not actual coding, I'll direct you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486328/vb-net-email-with-multiple-embedded-images).

Your current method isn't actually embedding the images and is making a link. What you want to do is add the images as linked resources. This WILL make your emails larger in size and slower to send, but as long as you aren't a spammer, you should be OK.

Alternatively, you could have an enterprise level failure plan where your server would go offline and a mirrored server in a different location would begin serving up the data/images.